# TestSettings file available in TFS but not through Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010, and yesterday I edited the `Local.testsetting` file (added a deployment item) and checked it in to TFS. Now I can see it in the TFS as a solution item, but when accessing `Test-> Edit Test Settings` I see a grayed out "no test settings available".

Any idea how to get my local setting back?

Comment: Well, as always - After different changes were checked in and I got latest, the file re-appeared. I have no idea how to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the solution/project containing the Local.testsetting file.  What happened is you simply closed out the project or solution and it is no longer in scope inside VS.  The simple act of adding a file to the deployment item would not cause it to be grayed out.  To verify this you can edit it again and remove that file.

All VS Menu's are context sensitive- a message saying "No Test Settings Available" is expected when the project/solution isn't open.

Comment: The solution *was* open when I was trying to re-open the file.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue after refactoring a number of solutions recently. For me, I had to ensure that my `Local.testsettings` was listed in the ProjectSection of my solution.

Open your solution in a text editor and check that the correct `Local.testsettings` file exists (and is in the correct path. Most likely this file is located in the same directory as the solution, as this example below shows):

```
Project("{<<GUID>>}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{<<GUID>>}"
ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
    MyProject.vsmdi = MyProject.vsmdi
    Local.testsettings = Local.testsettings
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

If you don't have this Solution Items section, right click your solution and select Add > Existing Item, and add your `Local.testsettings` file. This will add this value to your sln.